# Is there a way to underline spaces before text

Tags: html

Consider the following code:

```
<u> test </u>
```

This only underlines test + the space after test and not before. Why is this and how can I make it underline the first space also?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<u>&nbsp;test&nbsp;</u>
```

Or

```
u {
    white-space:pre;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/R3DbV/1)**

You can read all about how spaces are collapsed (or removed) at http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/text.html#propdef-white-space

Comment: This means changing the element content. It does not underline SPACE characters; instead, they have been changed to different characters, NO-BREAK SPACE characters.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela - how does `u { white-space: pre; }` change the content?

Comment: Changing space to `&nbsp;` (the first answer given) changes the content.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela - obviously. However my answer includes an alternate option as you can see that doesn't.

Comment: link to css3 specification: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-text-3/#propdef-white-space

Answer (score 2):

This is because all whitespace will collapse into a single whitspace. Try to remove any whitespace in front of the `<u>`tag. Something like this:

```
Some<span style='text-decoration: underline;'> underlined </span>text<br>
```

and a demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/8J2ZE/

You should btw use css to achieve styling, not markup

Answer (score 1):

The behavior depends on the browser (Chrome underlines the space after the word) and doesn’t seem to be prescribed in specifications. The element content is parsed and stored into the DOM with the spaces included, but it might not take part in things like underlining.

Using no-break spaces instead of spaces tends to cause underlining, but it changes the content and has side effects (e.g., no-break spaces prevent line breaks before and after).

Setting `white-space: pre` seems to cause underlining, though there is no logical reason why it should and no guarantee that it will, in future browsers. (Note that collapse of whitespace to a single space is quite distinct from the issue of rendering a single space.)

The conclusions depend on the context and on the reasons for wanting such underlining. Perhaps you can use a bottom border (which has well-defined rendering rules) instead of underline – note that the border is in a lower position, which may or may not be suitable (and on the other hand, you can set the color, thickness, and style of the border). E.g.,

```
<span style="border-bottom: solid 1px"> test </span>
```